# Play feedback when volume is changed via touch bar

Tags: audio, sound-volume, touch-bar

There is an audible 'pop' when I change volume using the slider in System Preferences. I can also hear it when volume is being unmuted using the soft button on touch bar.

I do not hear any feedback when volume is changed via touch bar.

I have tried tapping touch bar volume button and then dragging the slider, tapping volume icons around the slider, pressing and holding volume button without releasing touch bar; none of them provide any audible feedback.

This is true for both built-in speakers and 3.5mm output.

Is there a way of enabling feedback sound when volume is changed via touch bar?

Comment: Confirmed with my rMBP 15" 2017.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't possible in Sierra, which is probably a bug. In High Sierra enabling ‘Play feedback when volume is changed’ in Sound preferences enables the feedback pop when releasing your finger from the slider.

Answer (score -1):

Start by going to **System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects**.

Under the list of sound effects you should see two checkboxes, one labelled `Play feedback when volume is changed`. Check that box, and you should hear a feedback sound as the volume is changed.

Any time you touch the volume up/down button or release on the slider you will hear the feedback sound.

This sound will be different from the one in System Preferences, sounding more like a 'tick'

Comment: This setting is enabled (otherwise I would not hear the sound when changing the volume via System Preferences); still, releasing the slider does not produce any sound:(

Comment: @Julian - alright, something seems to be off with your sound. Even if that switch is disabled you can hear the blips in system preferences. Could you try [resetting your NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) for me? Something may be cached in there about sound. Note that this may affect your display resolution and time zone (if not set automatically)

Comment: Huh, Preferences' slider generate sound even if feedback is disabled indeed, thanks for that:) Sadly resetting NVRAM did not fix the touch bar slider issue

Comment: So NVRAM reset didn't do anything (just confirming)

Comment: No. And I am assuming the reset itself worked correctly (screen flashing during boot and then I could see a different (red) loading bar before login prompt. No settings in Preferences were affected as far as I can tell though

Comment: Alright, can you try using the 3-piece volume icon? [(looks like this)](http://i.imgur.com/XQGvPfb.png)

Comment: We should probably [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64479/discussion-between-jackson1442-and-julian).

Comment: On macs without a touch bar, if the "enable feedback" setting is disabled, holding `shift` while pressing the volume buttons overrides this and produces the feedback anyway. I believe the inverse is true also (if the setting is enabled then holding `shift` will disable the feedback).

Either way, `shift` does nothing with feedback sounds on macs with touch bar.